# Embedded Application Server

Tags: embeddedwebserver

I'm planning to do a C++ standalone desktop application which uses web / html as the main format of it's documents content.

I need suggestions for a good application server that can generate dynamic contents and can be easily embedded in my desktop application. It doesn't matter what server side programming languages it supports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your application will be used through a web-browser interface, which is the reason why you are generating HTML content. With that in mind, you can still use C/C++  for your both the front and back end logic through a web-server.

There are several small & fast web servers that support CGI services. You can then write your back-end servers using C/C++ as CGI services. You can also write your client using C/C++ with an embedded browser like Gecko or Webkit within it.

Answer (score 0):

there's nothing better than [Lua](http://lua.org) for embedding a language in a C/C++ application.  do that, and you can simply add [Xavante](http://www.keplerproject.org/xavante/), which with the full [Kepler](http://www.keplerproject.org/) environment supports very flexible and modern web apps.

(disclaimer: i'm one of the Xavante authors; but i'm writing this more because i love Lua than because of any pride about Xavante)